# Is there a way to set a custom hour cycle (different from 24h) for a date?

Tags: vba, algorithm, date, time

I am using VBA in Outlook to calculate the Service Level Agreement (expiration) of a ticket (email) starting from information contained in it.
The intervention time is 11h and 30 min and goes from 08:00 to 19:30 only on working days.
To know the working days I have no problems.

I know these tools: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_date_time.htm
but they are based on a 24 hour cycle.

Is there is a way to set a cycle other than 24h? (In my case one day is 11h 30m.)

Comment: take the full time variable and reduce it by 12.5 hours?

Comment: look at this example:
`Dim startDate As Variant
        Dim timeToAdd As Variant
        startDate = CDate("05/11/2020 19:00")
 MsgBox DateAdd("h", 6, startDate)`
 adding 6 hours to 05/11/2020 19:00 obtain 06/11/2020 01:00,  instead I want 06/11/2020 13:30
 
 because 6 hours are distribuited like this:
 
 - 30 min from 19:00 to 19:30 of day 5/11 
 - 5.30 hours starting from 8:00 of day 06/11 (therefore: 13:30)
 
 there an automatism for this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Comment of Mech made me think...
For considering a day costituited of less than 24h means that remaining hours (in my case 24H-11H:30M = 12H:30M) is the offset value to ignore (that is to skip).
therefore in my case:

```
Dim startDate As Variant
Dim newDate As Variant
startDate = CDate("05/11/2020 19:00")
newDate = DateAdd("h", 12, startDate) 'hours to skip
newDate = DateAdd("n", 30, newDate) 'n=minute to skip
newDate = DateAdd("h", 6, newDate) 'hours to add
MsgBox newDate 'shows 06/11/2020 13:30
```

I'll make an abstraction of this concept and released it on my GitHub.

Thanks Mech